# Nutritional sodium deficiency -- documented cases?

Tags: sodium

Are there documented cases of nutritional sodium deficiency? I'm curious what the symptoms are, and if it's possible to achieve them through dietary restrictions alone. I could only find examples of hyponatremia with causes other than nutritional deficiency.

Comment: It may not be only sodium but drinking distilled water can result in dizziness and " lightheaded". . A friend ( PhD Chem E, interestingly enough) tried this as an alternative to drinking ethanol , so it was somewhat successful.  I know of no documentation but he got the idea somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Two case reports of hyponatremia in infants fed exclusively with almond, nut, chestnut and soy milk or a homemade sesame seed emulsion were identified.  These cases appear to be due to inadequate sodium in the diet.

Fourreau D, Peretti N, Hengy B, et al. Complications carentielles suite à l'utilisation de « laits » végétaux, chez des nourrissons de deux mois et demi à 14 mois (quatre cas) [Pediatric nutrition: Severe deficiency complications by using vegetable beverages, four cases report]. Presse Med. 2013;42(2):e37-43. French. doi: 10.1016/j.lpm.2012.05.029. Epub 2012 Sep 28. PMID: 23021957.

Shohat M, Levy I, Levy Y, Nitzan M. Nutritional complications in an infant fed exclusively on homemade sesame seed emulsion. J Am Coll Nutr. 1989;8:167-9. doi: 10.1080/07315724.1989.10720291. PMID: 2708731.

According to Sterns, hyponatremia is not a disease but rather a pathophysiologic process indicating disturbed water homeostasis.

Sterns RH. Disorders of plasma sodium--causes, consequences, and correction. N Engl J Med. 2015;372:55-65. doi: 10.1056/NEJMra1404489. PMID:25551526.

Sterns states:

> Maximal dilution of urine prevents hyponatremia unless water intake is
> extraordinarily large (>1 liter per hour) (e.g., in patients with
> schizophrenia who drink water compulsively) or the rate of urinary
> solute excretion is extremely low (e.g., in beer drinkers who eat very
> little).

There are numerous case reports of a condition called “beer potomania”—excessive consumption of beer—which is characterized by hyponatremia.   Lodhi et al. explain “beer potomania” as follows:

> Beer potomania, a unique syndrome of hyponatremia, was first reported
> in 1972. It is described as the excessive intake of alcohol,
> particularly beer, together with poor dietary solute intake that leads
> to fatigue, dizziness, and muscular weakness. The low solute content
> of beer, and suppressive effect of alcohol on proteolysis result in
> reduced solute delivery to the kidney. The presence of inadequate
> solute in the kidney eventually causes dilutional hyponatremia
> secondary to reduced clearance of excess fluid from the body.

Lodhi MU, Saleem TS, Kuzel AR, et al. "Beer Potomania" - A Syndrome of Severe Hyponatremia with Unique Pathophysiology: Case Studies and Literature Review. Cureus. 2017;9(12):e2000. doi: 10.7759/cureus.2000. PMID: 29507848; PMCID: PMC5832394.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5832394/

Published case reports of beer potomania up to 2018 are cited in Joshi and Chou, who also explain the pathophysiology.

Joshi R, Chou S.  Beer Potomania: A View on the Dynamic Process of Developing Hyponatremia. Cureus 2018;10(7): e3024. DOI 10.7759/cureus.3024

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30254813/

Pica is a condition in which patients crave and chew substances with no nutritional value. Ice pica (pagophagia) is seen in patients with iron deficiency. A case report of hyponatremia due to excessive consumption of water because of ice pica (pagophagia) was identified.

Bedanie G, Tikue A, Thongtan T, et al.  Pica/Pagophagia-Associated Hyponatremia: Patient Presenting With Seizure. Cureus 2020;12(7): e9330. DOI 10.7759/cureus.9330
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32742885/

Answer (score 1):

[Tea and Toast syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_and_toast_syndrome) is a well-known cause of hyponatremia due to a diet with restricted salt/protein intake but abundant fluids ("tea and toast"), usually occurring among elderly who are unable to cook or feed themselves properly. This is especially dangerous when taking other salt-wasting medication such as diuretics.

[Symptoms of hyponatremia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5694198/):

> symptomatology of acute hyponatremia (developed in <48 h) such as **nausea, vomiting, headache, stupor, coma and seizures**, as well as manifestations (even mild) associated with chronic hyponatremia, such as **fatigue, cognitive impairment, gait deficits, falls, adverse effects on bone quality (eg, osteoporosis) and fractures**, are more frequent and severe in elderly patients

Source:

Filippatos TD, Makri A, Elisaf MS, Liamis G. Hyponatremia in the elderly: challenges and solutions. Clin Interv Aging. 2017;12:1957-1965. Published 2017 Nov 14. doi:10.2147/CIA.S138535